# Inserting directory in existing directory structure in unix

Tags: unix, directory-structure

I have a directory structure something like : 
/etc/home/d1/d2/d3/d4

The last directory d4 contains some files so it is not empty.

But by mistake I forgot to create one more directory in between say d0
So I need to change my directory structure to :
/etc/home/d0/d1/d2/d3/d4

So my question is - is there any way to introduce this new directory in existing path or I have to do all the donkey work? :P

Comment: I know etc/home sounds stupid.. its just an example :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory under your home directory with name `d0`. Then use the `mv` command to move `d1` to `d0`. All directories and files under `d1` should get moved to `d0` giving you the desired structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir /etc/home/d0
mv /etc/home/d1 /etc/home/d0
```

This is quite different from the single command (when `/etc/home/d0` does not exist as a directory):

```
mv /etc/home/d1 /etc/home/d0
```

That might be a little confusing.  The first creates a directory and moves the hierarchy into it.  The second just renames one level in the hierarchy, which was not what you wanted.

Comment: Right, the behavior of `mv` is quite different depending on whether the second argument is the name of an existing directory. When it is, I usually append `/.` to the target name, so it will fail rather than renaming the source if I've mistyped something.